# User authentication using servlet 3.0 login in Jsf 2 not working

Tags: jsf, tomcat, servlets, authentication, jsf-2

Trying to create an application with a login page and using the Servlet 3.0 login method. I have defined the realm in tomcat and configured web.xml accordingly. But when I try to access any page even login page, it does not get rendered and I can see JSF tags in the code. I don't know if I am missing something. Details are as follow
Following is the what I have placed in web.xml.

```
<security-constraint>
<display-name>Restricted</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Restricted Area</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
<role-name>user</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
 <login-config>
   <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/index.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
  <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Following is the realm defined in tomcat

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?user=user&amp;password=password"
            userTable="users" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="userpass"
            userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="rolename" digest="MD5"/>
```

The code for login is

```
public String login(){
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    try {
        //Login via the Servlet Context
        request.login(username, password);
        return "success";
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid Login", null));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "failure";
}
```

Let me know I am doing anything wrong

---

**Update** Thanks guys it started to work. I had to change some url mappings in the web.xml and rearrange folders for security settings. Currently It is working but now just having a weird issue. I have defined

```
<form-login-config>
 <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
 <form-error-page>/index.xhtml</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

And now web.xml show an error on

```
<form-login-page>
```

and complains that

> Description Resource Path Location Type error: Attribute form-error-page references to /index.jsp that does not exist in web content web.xml /XXXX/WebContent/WEB-INF

I have no idea where this is coming from as I am not using any jsp file. Any clues

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the edit you did to the answer you merged as well, it really helps when people do that.

Answer (score 2):

So, the `FacesServlet` has not been invoked. This means that the URL of the login page did not match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as you've definied in `web.xml`. According to the URL pattern of your restricted area which is been set on `/faces/*`, I'll assume that it is the same URL pattern as you've definied for the `FacesServlet`.

So, fix it accordingly:

```
<form-login-page>/faces/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
<form-error-page>/faces/index.xhtml</form-error-page>
```

However, I would suggest to use a mapping of the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml` instead, so that you never need to worry about putting `/faces` in the path nor that the enduser would be able to see raw JSF source code whenever the enduser removes `/faces` from the URL in browser address bar.

---

**Update**: That's an IDE-specific validation error. The IDE which you're using is pretending to be smarter than it actually is. If your webapp runs and works fine, just ignore it. You can if necessary shut up the IDE XML validation in its preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in the `web.xml` and change (in the `<security-constraint>` section)

```
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: As per your edit, `/*` is pretty restrictive. You would be forced to inline all CSS/JS code in the HTML instead of having them referenced as `<link>`, `<script>`, etc in order to use them in your login page. You would also not be able to put images on the login page as well unless you rely on browsers supporting the data URI scheme. I think an URL pattern of `*.xhtml` is better, or a (real!) folder like `/app/*`.

Comment: I prefer defining a `security-constraint` without `auth-constraint` tag for the `/img/*`, `/style/*` etc., so the are accessible without login.